# What does "street pattern" mean?

Tags: meaning

I am learning about this [post](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/City_block), which says

> A city block is the smallest area that is surrounded by streets. City
>   blocks are the space for buildings within the street pattern of a
>   city, and form the basic unit of a city's urban fabric.

What does "street pattern" mean in this context?

Comment: I think the author means the interweaving streets form a pattern, like a photo from above of the city!

Answer (score 1):

A pattern can be understood as a ['design or form'](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pattern). So the blocks are the space for buildings within the design or form of the streets of a city. The streets might form squares or triangles or odd shapes between them, depending on how their layout is designed. This combination of shapes formed by the streets is the 'street pattern'.